# Spark ignoreCorruptFiles config is ignoring non-corrupt files when first file is corrupt

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, corrupt

I have a folder which contains one corrupt file and other proper files(Non-corrupt)

Path: s3://temp-bucket/test/
Files:

s3://temp-bucket/test/a_corrupt_file.parquet
s3://temp-bucket/test/b_proper_file1.parquet

s3://temp-bucket/test/b_proper_file2.parquet

```
spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "false")
val corruptTest = spark.read.parquet("s3://temp-bucket/test/")
```

Above code fails with the below exception

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file:

```
spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
val corruptTest = spark.read.parquet("s3://temp-bucket/test/")
```

Above code fails with the below exception

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet

With ignoreCorruptFiles=true, when the first file(lexicographically) is corrupt, spark is ignoring all the files including proper non-corrupt files

Comment: One solution I found is providing schema while reading.
But I don't know the schema before reading

Answer (score 0):

df = spark.read.option("ignoreCorruptFiles",true).parquet( .... )
seems to work in python but not in scala.

That would allow you to get the schema - provided not all the parquet is corrupt... and even save the uncorrupt records to a new file.